# Visualizar webCam en Java

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy creando una aplicación en java que me permita visualizar mi webCam en un panel definido para tal fin, pero no lo consigo. Estoy usando la librerías

> bridj-0.7.0.jar, slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar, webcam-capture-0.3.12.jar, slf4j-simple-1.7.25.jar

He creado un método para arrancar la webCam:

```
public void arrancarWebCam(){
    webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
    webcam.setViewSize(webcam.getViewSizes()[0]);
    panelWebCam = new WebcamPanel(webcam, true);
    panelWebCam.setPreferredSize(webcam.getViewSize());
    panelWebCam.setOpaque(true);
    panelWebCam.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    panelWebCam.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);
    jpPanelFoto.add(panelWebCam);

    if (initialized.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                panelWebCam.start();
                webcam.open();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

el cual lo he ido montando obteniendo información de distintas fuentes de github y demás sitios. Es la primera vez que intento acceder a una webcam y me encuentro bastante perdido con esto.

H e estado leyendo y algunas personas han creado proyectos con Maven, lo he intentado también, pero desconozco como se hace un proyecto en Maven, lo he intentado, pero cuando lo tengo todo correcto y sin errores en las dependencias, la aplicación no hace nada, no arranca entorno de ventanas ni nada.

El método que he comentado anteriormente, lo llamo desde mi constructor en la clase, no me da errores de ningún tipo, anteriormente usando las librerías Xarxos, pero tampoco he sabido usarla, agradecería alguna ayuda por favor.

Un saludo

Answer (score 1):

**Solución:**

Ya lo he conseguido hacer, gracias de todas formas, la solución ha sido esta:

```
  public void ArrancarWebCam() {
     webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
     webcam.setViewSize(WebcamResolution.VGA.getSize());

     WebcamPanel panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
     panel = new WebcamPanel(webcam);
     panel.setFPSDisplayed(false);
     panel.setDisplayDebugInfo(false);
     panel.setImageSizeDisplayed(false);
     panel.setMirrored(true);
     panel.setSize(webcam.getViewSize());

    jpDatosPaciente.add(panel);
     pack();
     panel.setBounds(850, 40, 150, 150);
     panel.setVisible(true);
}
```

y posteriormente hacer una llamada a este método desde el constructor